Как в терминале Windows 11 сделать подтверждение каждой команды перед выполнением в VS Code?
Хочу реализовать так называемую «защиту от дурака» — перед выполнением любой команды через терминал она должна запрашивать подтверждение на выполнение и показывать описание того, что делает команда — например, создать папку? - y/n; удалить папку? - y/n; установить такой-то пакет? — y/n и тд. Идеально было бы если такое можно распространить на все терминалы в системе, но как минимум это нужно в VS Code, т.к работать я буду оттуда. Может можно скачать какую-то утилиту для подобных настроек? Почитал про PScmdlet, но это слишком сложно для меня, поэтому пожалуйста, предлагайте решения как можно проще или объясните максимально подробно.
